# how can I dynamically get the variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on React app, but I think this is most likely JavaScript problem. I have many variables with a pattern, `VARIABLE_NAME_{number}`, example, `FOO_1, FOO_2 ...` so on. In my function, it takes index as input and return mapped output.

```
import power from 'customClass';
const getOneOfFoo = (theIndex) => {
  power()
   .then(data => {
      let result = data?.first?.second?.FOO_{theIndex}?.name ; // how can I declare this one with passing input?
     // example, if theIndex=59, I want to have
     // let result = data?.first?.second?.FOO_59?.name;
      resolve({
          result: result
      });
     })
   .catch(err => console.log(err))
  });
```

The data object structure is like this,

```
data
 |-first
     |-second
         |-FOO_1
            |-name
         |-FOO_2
            |-name
         |-FOO_3
            |-name
         |-FOO_4
            |-name
         ...
```

In line 5, I want to assign `result` dynamically. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If I understand your question right, you can access properties like [].  For example SomeObject["someProperty"] or in your case SomeObject[INDEX]

Answer (score 2):

You can treat it like a dictionary.
Here's an example:

```js
const data = {
  'FOO_1': { name: 'Kenobi' },
  'FOO_2': { name: 'Skywalker' },
  'FOO_3': { name: 'Yoda' },
  'FOO_4': { name: 'Kylo' },
  'FOO_5': { name: 'Sidious' }
}

function getVar(index) {
  let result = data?.[`FOO_${index}`]?.name;
  return result;
}

console.log(getVar(1)); // expected output: Kenobi
console.log(getVar(2)); // expected output: Skywalker
console.log(getVar(3)); // expected output: Yoda
console.log(getVar(4)); // expected output: Kylo
console.log(getVar(5)); // expected output: Sidious
console.log(getVar(6)); // expected output: undefined
```

So for your case, it would probably be something like this:

```js
import power from 'customClass';
const getOneOfFoo = (theIndex) => {
  power()
   .then(data => {
      let result = data?.first?.second?.[`FOO_${theIndex}`]?.name;
      resolve({
          result: result
      });
     })
   .catch(err => console.log(err))
  });
```

And btw, resolve doesn't seem to be defined.

Answer (score -1):

```
let result = data?.first?.second[`FOO_${theIndex}`]?.name ;
```

u can use [] with inside is string which is name of property

Comment: Wrong syntax. Supposed to be `let result = data?.first?.second?.[\`FOO_${theIndex}\`]?.name`;

Comment: i just try one and it's okay,

Comment: Backticks for template literals ***DO NOT*** mix with normal strings. Also see the [TC39 proposal for optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining#syntax). It goes something like this: `obj?.[index]`